# Efficiently rotate image and paste into a larger image using NumPy and OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, optimization, transformation

I am rotating images and pasting them on a screen-sized (4K) canvas using the following code but this implementation takes more than a hundred milliseconds per image rotated and pasted.  The program I am using this in needs to do this a lot so it would be beneficial to speed things up and I also presume given this is a pretty standard kind of operation that this code is very optimizable.  I would be grateful for any guidance on how to optimize it.

It may be relevant to mention that the various rotated images are usually quite close and sometimes overlap which is why I am doing the masking but that is one of the places that I think maybe I am being inefficient.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

canvas = np.zeros((2160, 3840, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

img_path = PATH_TO_IMAGE
image = cv2.imread(img_path)

offset_from_center = 10
rotation_angle = 45

width = image.shape[1]
pivot_point = (width/2, offset_from_center)

rotation_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(pivot_point, -rotation_angle, 1.)

canvas_height = canvas.shape[0]
canvas_width = canvas.shape[1]

rotation_mat[0, 2] += canvas_width/2 - pivot_point[0]
rotation_mat[1, 2] += canvas_height/2 - pivot_point[1]

rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(image,
                               rotation_mat,
                               (canvas_width, canvas_height))

alpha = np.sum(rotated_image, axis=-1) > 0

alpha = alpha.astype(float)

alpha = np.dstack((alpha, alpha, alpha))

rotated_image = rotated_image.astype(float)
canvas = canvas.astype(float)

foreground = cv2.multiply(alpha, rotated_image)
canvas = cv2.multiply(1.0 - alpha, canvas)

canvas = cv2.add(foreground, canvas)
canvas = canvas.astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: you should use a graphics library, preferably GPU-accelerated. opencv is for vision, not graphics. look into opengl maybe. it's easy to get started if you start with the good old "immediate" API first. -- don't dstack the alpha. numpy has broadcasting rules. just "unsqueeze" it (reshape to insert a 1-sized dimension)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks!  I had a feeling the answer might be to do this with different tools but great to have your confirmation of that and suggestion of OpenGL. And also thanks for the suggestion re: the alpha, that is the kind of thing I am generally trying to internalize to generally write more efficient numpy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick profile shows that `np.sum(rotated_image, axis=-1)` is particularly slow. Other subsequent operations are a bit slow, too, especially the array multiplications and the `dstack`.

---

### Numpy-based optimization

The first thing to know is that `np.sum` will automatically convert the type of the array to a **wider type** before doing the reduction. In practice a 64-bit int. This means an **8 time bigger array to reduce in memory** so a significant slowdown. That being said, the biggest issue is that **Numpy is not optimized for reducing very small dimension**: it iterates over each array line using a quite inefficient approach and the iteration is far more expensive than adding 3 integers. One solution is to do a manual addition to significantly speed up this. Here is an example:

```py
tmp = rotated_image.astype(np.uint16)
alpha = (tmp[:,:,0] + tmp[:,:,1] + tmp[:,:,2]) > 0
```

Note that this is sub-optimal and using **Cython or Numba** can speed this up even more (by a large margin). Another alternative is to operate on a **transposed image**.

Then, when you do `alpha.astype(float)`, 64-bit floats are used which takes a lot of memory so any manipulation is slow. 64-bit floats are clearly not required here. 32-bit floats can be used instead. In fact, PC GPUs nearly always use 32-bit float to compute images since 64-bit operations are much more expensive (they require a lot of energy and a lot more transistors).

`np.dstack` is not needed since Numpy can make use of broadcasting (with `alpha[:,:,None]`) so *avoid big temporary arrays* like this. Unfortunately, Numpy broadcasting slow things down in practice...

`cv2.multiply` can be replaced by `np.multiply` which has a special **parameter `out` for faster in-place operations** (30% faster on my machine). The `cv2.multiply` also has an equivalent `dst` parameter as pointed out by @ChristophRackwitz. Both functions runs equally fast on my machine.

Here is a faster implementation summing up all of this:

```py
tmp = rotated_image.astype(np.uint16)
alpha = (tmp[:,:,0] + tmp[:,:,1] + tmp[:,:,2]) > 0

alpha = alpha.astype(np.float32)

alpha = np.dstack((alpha, alpha, alpha))

rotated_image = rotated_image.astype(np.float32)
canvas = canvas.astype(np.float32)

foreground = np.multiply(alpha, rotated_image)
np.subtract(1.0, alpha, out=alpha)
np.multiply(alpha, canvas, out=canvas)

np.add(foreground, canvas, out=canvas)
canvas = canvas.astype(np.uint8)
```

Thus, the optimized solution is 4 times faster. It is still far from being fast but this pushes a bit Numpy to its limits.

---

### Speeding up the code with Numba

Creating **many big temporary arrays** and operating on small dimensions is far from being efficient. This can be solved by computing pixel in-flight in a basic loop optimized by a (JIT) compiler like Numba or Cython to produce a fast **native code**. Here is an implementation:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(uint8[:,:,::1], uint8[:,:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(img, canvas):
    for i in nb.prange(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            ir = np.float32(img[i, j, 0])
            ig = np.float32(img[i, j, 1])
            ib = np.float32(img[i, j, 2])
            cr = np.float32(canvas[i, j, 0])
            cg = np.float32(canvas[i, j, 1])
            cb = np.float32(canvas[i, j, 2])
            alpha = np.float32((ir + ig + ib) > 0)
            inv_alpha = np.float32(1.0) - alpha
            cr = inv_alpha * cr + alpha * ir
            cg = inv_alpha * cg + alpha * ig
            cb = inv_alpha * cb + alpha * ib
            canvas[i, j, 0] = np.uint8(cr)
            canvas[i, j, 1] = np.uint8(cg)
            canvas[i, j, 2] = np.uint8(cb)

compute(rotated_image, canvas)
```

Here are performance results on my 6-core machine (repeated 7 times):

```
Before:            0.427  s     1x
Optimized Numpy:   0.113  s    ~4x
Numba:             0.0023 s  ~186x
```

As we can see, the Numba implementation is much much faster than the optimized Numpy implementation. If this is not enough, you can compute this on the GPU which is more efficient for such a task. It should be much faster and use less energy because GPUs have dedicated units for doing alpha-blending (and wider SIMD units). One solution is to use CUDA which only works on Nvidia GPUs. Another solution is to use OpenCL or even OpenGL for this. This should be a bit more complex than using Numba though.

Comment: please check your claims regarding the OpenCV [`cv.multiply`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga979d898a58d7f61c53003e162e7ad89f). it *also* has an "out" parameter you can use. and it's not *converting* anything to fp64 unless that is specifically requested using the `dtype` argument/flag. by default it creates a result of the same type as the first operand... which may be fp64 here, but that wouldn't be OpenCV's fault. -- and please show the speed advantage, if any, of "fastmath" (vs numba without fastmath), and discuss its downsides, or link to a discussion

Comment: When I used the `dst` parameter of `cv2.multiply` I got typing issues and just ended up using `np.multiply`. You are right it can be used the same way than `np.multiply` and the two functions result in the same performance on my machine (both with and without `out`/`dst`). For the cast, the function actually refuses to operate on mixed types. It explicitly states:  "*When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified*" so It does not make implicit conversions at all. I removed this part.

Comment: I though OpenCV use `np.multiply` internally so I explained the way Numpy works but it looks like they use their own implementation (I am not entirely convinced since most of the time of `cv2.multiply` sent most of its time in the Numpy multiarray/umath functions). At least they do not have the same interface (Numpy does implicit casts by default while OpenCV do not). Thank you for pointing this out. Regarding fastmath, it should not impact the results in this specific case and it turns out it does not impact performance either so I simply removed it.

Comment: Just a note on fastmath: it should not impact results because FP values are comming from small integers so they should have a perfect representation. Iven if it would not be the case, the precision due to the non-associativity should still not impact results because of the final cast. NaN and Inf values are not present so this does not have any impact either. Rounding is not an issue since alpha is a boolean 0-1 value and FP is perfect here due to integers. In fact, I think FP operations could simply be replaced by integer ones (one need to be careful though).

Comment: OpenCV uses no numpy at all. OpenCV is a C++ library first, with its own numerics. the Python bindings map between numpy arrays and OpenCV's `cv::Mat` type.

Comment: Yeah. I found the Numpy call suspicious, so I rebuilt Numpy in debug mode and used a low-level profiler to track what was the call and it was simply the `1.0 - alpha` and not the `cv2.multiply`. This leads to a slightly faster Numpy version. So, I confirm there is not Numpy calls in the binding (besides the raw data Numpy extraction). Btw, this is a bit sad there is no (fast) FMA vectorized version in Numpy, and it looks like the same in OpenCV.

Comment: I guess one is not meant to write comments that merely express appreciation but, wow, this is great!  It is going to take me a while to work through this and understand all the bits and pieces.  And I think it is likely that I'll apply some of these solutions/ideas to other performance bottle-necks.